# DOT Overwide node error

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a large DOT file that I am trying to graph in GraphViz using DOT.   I used the following command:
`dot -Tpng -o d:\GUIForm\test2.png d:\GUIForm\graph_2291547484206256890.dot.tmp`

I got the following error:

`Error: Edge length 65873.000000 larger than maximum 65535 allowed. Check for overwide node(s).`

The syntax of the DOT file is correct but there are 230k lines in the DOT file (it is a function call graph).  Any idea to circumvent this error?  Or is there a hard limit on the size of files that GraphViz can handle?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem node may require "FIXEDSIZE=true" in order to prevent the bulging. Can you upload your DOT file for examination?

Comment: The dot file is about 10MB wide. Not sure if I can copy/paste it here.  The problem is there are a few 100 hundreds of nodes. Can I add FIXEDSIZE="true" as a "global setting" for the entire DOT file?

Comment: Can you share the file via Dropbox? stackoverflow@michaeloboyle.com The global setting is worth a try but it will likely have undesirable results elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a hard limit based on `USHRT_MAX` (see GraphViz's position.c). Another option for trying to avoid it is to uniformly scale down the size of the nodes (e.g. by globally setting the `fontsize` attribute lower).

Comment: Is this different on Windows and Linux? I get this error on Linux, but not on Windows.